# Ambiguous file/directory listing component in UNIX(ls-la)

Tags: macos, unix, ls

Total noob question, but I am looking @ the permissions of a directory that looks like this:

```
drwxr-xr-x   3 username  groupname     102 Sep  4 14:15 .file
```

What I am trying to figure out is what exactly is the number(3) between the file/directory permissions and the file/directory owner?

I am referencing a bunch of different online documentation, including the man pages and this page here:

http://www.brandx.net/support/usingtelnet/unixint.shtml

But none of them specify what number is? I am trying to change to 4

Comment: It's the number of [hard links](http://superuser.com/a/171946/356580).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `3` provided in your example is a hard link. See the links below for more information.

Wiki:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link

Hard Link vs Soft Link:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-unixlinux-symbolic-soft-and-hard-links.html